Table showing above section
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{ragged2e,tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\section{RESULTS AND DISCUSSIONS}

In this section, we carried out simulation experiments to compare our proposed solutions with traditional Q-learning, Cooperative Q-learning, and random algorithm. We used the tools, packages, and libraries we mentioned under section \ref{des_dev}.\vspace{3mm}

\subsection{Simulation Environment and Simulation Parameters}
In out simulation, we used simulation environment almost as same as \cite{kiran2020reinforcement}, except that putting UE per FBS to 30 to simulate our algorithms in a high dimensional state space and compare with existing algorithms. We set task tolerable delay between 5-10ms and task size follows uniform distribution between $2 \times 10^5$ and $5 \times 10^5$ bits. The table \ref{tab:simenv} shows the simulation environment.\vspace{3mm}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm} | p{5cm}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Description}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Value}} \\ \hline
Number CS &                         1\\
Number of FBSs &                    10\\
Number of UEs per FBS &             30\\
Edge server CPU capacity &          20GHz\\
Max UE Computation &                10GHz\\
Task tolerable delay &              5 $\approx$ 10ms\\
Channel power gain &                127 + 30 * $\log(d)$\\
Gaussian channel noise,$\sigma^2$ & $3 * 10^{-15} W$\\
Transmit power of UE, $p_i$ &       0.5 W\\
Total battery capacity &            500j\\
Transmission bandwidth of UE, $B$ & 10 MHz\\
Task data size &                    min $2 \times 10^5$ bits, max $5 \times 10^5$ bits\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Simulation environment}
\label{tab:simenv}
\end{center}
\end{table}

Table \ref{tab:simpara} shows the important learning parameters utilised in the AHP-DDQN method. The dense-layer setup contains hidden layers with 256 neurons, which enable the neural network to determine complicated patterns in the data. The N-step for Q-learning is set to 1, suggesting that the algorithm updates its knowledge based on a single step ahead, which is usual for Q-learning. The replay buffer capacity of 10,000 helps the model to learn from a varied range of past experiences, boosting its ability to make intelligent decisions.\vspace{3mm}

The target network is updated gently (also known as a soft update) with a parameter of 0.005, meaning that 0.5\% of the primary network's parameters are copied to the target network at each update step, facilitating stable learning. The initial epsilon value of 1.0 indicates that the algorithm starts with a comprehensive exploration, selecting actions randomly to thoroughly examine the environment at the beginning. This exploration rate eventually reduces to an ultimate epsilon value of 0.1, guaranteeing that the algorithm continues to explore novel actions 10\% of the time even after considerable training.\vspace{3mm}

The target synchronisation interval is set to 1000 training steps, demonstrating the target network parameters are updated from the main network every 1000 steps, which helps maintain stability throughout learning. The learning rate is 0.001, suggesting a modest step size for each iteration, ensuring slow and consistent learning modifications. The training batch size of 32 means that 32 experiences are sampled from the replay buffer for each training iteration, allowing for efficient and effective learning. The overall episode count is set to 10,000. Finally, the discount factor is 0.99, signalling that future benefits are significantly weighted, fostering long-term planning and optimization. These parameters are set to balance exploration and exploitation, provide consistent learning, and optimise task offloading.\vspace{3mm}

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{10cm} | p{5cm}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Parameter}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Value}} \\ \hline
Dense-layer setup (Hidden) & 256 \\
N-step for Q-learning & 1 \\
Replay Buffer capacity & 10,000 \\
The target network smoothly copies the parameter & 0.005 \\
Initial epsilon (Exploration) & 1.0 \\
Final epsilon (Exploration) & 0.1 \\
Target synchronization interval training steps & 1000 \\
Learning rate & 0.001 \\
Training batch size & 32 \\
Maximum episode & 10000\\
Discount factor & 0.99 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Learning Parameters of the AHP-DDQN Algorithm}
\label{tab:simpara}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\subsection{Simulation Results}

\end{document}

The table supposed to show below the subsection simulation environment and parameters. Instead it displayed above section title


Try using \usepackage[section]{placeins}

With \begin{table} you don't give latex a lot of choices to find a good place for your table. Better use something like \begin{table}[htbp]

Off-topic: You should not use \begin{center}…\end{center} in the table, but just \centering.

(and the center environment adds additional vertical space, use \centering instead)

Off-topic: Please get rid of all \vspace{3mm} directives and, instead, insert the instruction \setlength\parskip{3mm} in the preamble.

Don't use * as multiplication sign. Use \times or \cdot instead.

To get proper spacing between your numbers and units, have a look at the siunitx package

Thank you all bros. It really helped me a lot. @Mane32 answered first and works good and samcater_is_at_topanswers.xys answer works as well. But it seems I cannot vote best answer. Can you upload it as answer so that I can vote?

Instead of the \vspace{3mm} I would suggest to add \usepackage[skip=3mm]{parskip}. See the manual of package parskip for more information.

@cabohah - Loading the parskip package in the way you suggest will also set \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}.

@Mico Yes, and this is intended, because using both indent and skip is unusual. AFAIR it was Jan Tschichold who named it “nonsense” (or was it Paul Renner?). However, if you want, you can read the manual to learn how to leave the indent unchanged using option indent. Referring to the manual and also adding a link to the package (where you can also find the manual) was also intended.
